# How can I use a string as argument for a method that takes an enum?

Tags: java, enums, setter

I have a class `TestCase`. Inside of this I have the inner class `Test`. Inside the class `enum OwnerType` are setters and getters of the enum.

```
public static final class Test{
    public enum OwnerType {
        User("User"), 
        Role("Role");
    }

    public OwnerType getOwnerType() {
        return m_ownerType;
    }

    public void setOwnerType(OwnerType m_ownerType) {
        this.m_ownerType = m_ownerType;
    }
}
```

`Test` is  the inner class in my case. I am trying to set the value with JSON key

```
private Test createTest(JSONObject obj) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setOwnerType(JSONUtil.getStringValue(obj, JSON_KEY)); // Gives error
    return test;
}
```

It gives an error

> The method `setOwnerType(TestCase.Test.OwnerType)` in the type `TestCase.Test` is not applicable for the arguments (`String`).

How can I convert the value or set it to the `createTest` method?

Comment: What is the actual value in the JSON? What is the complete, compilable code of the enum?

Comment: The above code doesn't compile, you need to change the enum code to `public enum OwnerType { User, Role; }` or you need a constructor for `OwnerType` that takes a String-typed argument.

Comment: Yes. The constructor I have like private final String value;private OwnerType(String value) {this.value = value;}

Comment: Ok. You can already get the name of the enum using `m_ownerType.name()` or `m_ownerType.toString()` (check Javadoc for when to use which)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `OwnerType#valueOf(String name)` method :

```
String name = JSONUtil.getStringValue(obj, JSON_KEY);
test.setOwnerType(Test.OwnerType.valueOf(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to [parse it into an `enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) first.

Try this instead:

```
test.setOwnerType(Test.OwnerType.valueOf(JSONUtil.getStringValue(obj, JSON_KEY)));
```

Note that you can either do `Enum.valueOf(YourEnum.class, stringValue)` and `YourEnum.valueOf(stringValue)`.